# What happens if multiple players pass the victory threshold simultaneously in Diplomacy?

Tags: diplomacy, variants

**This question is specifically about diplomacy variants, not the core game.**

In classic diplomacy, the victory threshold is `n/2 + 1` supply centers (18 out of 34 supply centers), so only one person can ever be passed it at any given time.  But this formula isn't used by all variants.  For example, [Imperial Diplomacy II](https://www.vdiplomacy.com/variants.php?variantID=81) has a victory threshold of 70 supply centers out of 172, which is notably less than half.

So, what happens if more than one player passes the victory threshold in the same year on such a variant?

Given this situation isn't possible in the base game, I don't think the core rules cover this situation, in which case sub-cannon sources must be considered.  Sources I'd consider include:

- Does any variant with a sub-half victory threshold specify how to handle such a situation?
- How do web-based diplomacy platforms like webdiplomacy.net and vdiplomacy.com handle this?
- Is there anything in Diplomacy tournament rules that is relevant?

Comment: If two players both have achieved the victory conditions, then I would say that they are both winners.